# Exact numerical solution to non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We're given the initial value problem below:

\begin{align}
y'(t)=4t\sqrt{y(t)}-\lambda (y(t)-(1+t^2)^2), \quad y(0) = a, \quad (a,\lambda)\in\mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}

For which $\lambda$ and $a$ would you be able to solve this ODE exactly using a fourth order accurate numerical method? By this it is meant that the fifth derivative of $y(t)$ equals zero, i.e. the solution $y(t)$ can be assumed to be a fourth order polynomial.

Obvious values would be $\lambda = 0$, then $y(t)=t^4 + 2\sqrt{a}\,t^2+a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$ (using separation of variables). Another case is $a = 1$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, but would there be a way to find all values?

The function looks very similar to a lagrangian equation since $y(t) = (1+t^2)^2$ is the solution to the problem when $\lambda = 0$ and $a = 1$, but this hasn't really helped. Another thing we've tried is to express $y$ as a finite taylor expansion (since fifth derivative and up are 0), but again it does not lead us any further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since there is a square root in the equation, you can be sure that the solution will be an order $4$ polynomial with $2$ double od $1$ quadruple zero. Is this helpful?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "2 double od 1 quadruple zero?"

Comment: Either it will be $C(t-a)^2 (t-b)^2$ or it will be $C(t-a)^4$. There is no other way for a polynomial of order $\leq 4$ to solve the equation. It also must be of order $4$ because there is a $t^4$ on the right hand side of the equation. From this, it also follows that $C=1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will see if I can solve it now.

Comment: I'm still not sure how this will let me say anything about $\lambda$. If we set $y(t) = (t-r_1)^2(t-r_2)^2$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are roots and might be equal, then we know that $y(0) = (-r_1)^2(-r_2)^2 = r_1^2r_2^2 = a \geq 0.$ But I don't know about $\lambda.$

Comment: Yes, but you have to also consider the actual equation. Plugging in $y$ gives you some equations to solve, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{This is more of a comment}$

If we make the substitution $y = v^{2}$ we can obtain  transform the ode as
$$
v^{'} = 2t - \frac{\lambda}{2v}\left(v^{2} - f(t)\right)
$$
where 
$$
f(t) = \left(1+t^{2}\right)^{2}
$$
if we set $\phi = v - \sqrt{f} = v - \left(1 + t^{2}\right)$.
We obtain:
$$
\phi^{'} + 2t=2t - \frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{\phi\left(\phi - 2\sqrt{f}\right)}{\phi + \sqrt{f}} 
$$
which reduces to 
$$
\phi^{'} = \frac{\lambda}{2}\frac{\phi\left(\phi - 2\left(1 + t^{2}\right)\right)}{\phi + \left(1 + t^{2}\right)} = \frac{\lambda}{2}\phi\left[1 - \frac{3\left(1 + t^{2}\right)}{\phi + \left(1 + t^{2}\right)}\right] 
$$
From here i haven't figured out a why to reduce this further. I have used $\chi = \frac{\phi}{\left(1 + t^{2}\right)}$
which lead to
$$
\frac{\chi^{'}}{\chi} = \frac{\chi - 2}{\chi + 1} - \frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{ln}\left(1 + t^{2}\right)
$$